# How to turn this into single Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.each( Variable, function() {
    // do something to each iteration in variable
});
```

And I want that to run once when the page loads, and then again every time when the user scrolls.

Until now I've duplicaterd the code twice to get it to work this way. So one copy/paste of the code that runs when the js file is loaded, and then pasted it again inside a scroll listener, so the final code looks like this:

```
$.each( Variable, function() {
    // do something to each iteration in variable
});
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    $.each( Variable, function() {
        // do something to each iteration in variable
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make the code run on load and during scroll without duplicating the code?

Comment: have you tried creating a function that does what you want that you can call in each place you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function `fn` and call it the first time, and on every scroll event :

```
var fn = function() {
  $.each( Variable, function() {
    // do something
  });
} 

fn()
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    fn()
});
```

You also can do :

```
fn()
$(window).scroll(fn);
```